# jimp not sending saved image

Tags: node.js, image-manipulation, discord.js

I'm trying to get image manipulation setup for a discord bot of mine, using lib discord.js. I'm grabbing args[0] from the command, and adding that text onto the image, saving it, sending it, and then deleting it with fs. This is my code below:

```
const Jimp = require('jimp');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
// Information
name: 'test',
aliases: [],
description: "test af.",
usage: "<args>",
args: {
    req: true,
    min: 1,
},

// Function

run: async (client, command, msg, args) => {
    Jimp.read("img/brain.jpg").then(function(image){
        Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_32_BLACK).then(function (font) {
        image.resize(542, 767);
        image.print(font, 16, 22, args[0]);
        image.write('brain.jpg');
        });
    });
    await msg.channel.send({
        files: [
            "brain.jpg"
        ]
    });
    fs.unlinkSync('brain.jpg');
    }
}
```

The problem we have is, when doing the command and adding the arguments, so for example: ".test argshere" it prints the text on the image and saves it, but when it tries to send the image it says it cannot find it in that directory, but if I go into the folder it is there. I believe it is trying to send before it has even saved yet. I've tried awaiting print, write and msg.channel.send but nothing seemed to work.

I'd also like to ask how I could add a sort of "text box" onto an image, so if there is too much letters in one line the text will go onto another line, as I don't want the text going over the memes. This is the image below:
[brain image meme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NukN.jpg)

Comment: Can you show your folder structure

Answer (score 0):

You use two callbacks to write the file, and then immediately after put code that will run before the callbacks. This is an asynchronous problem. If you put the send code after your write function, that should fix your issue.

```
run: async (client, command, msg, args) => {
  Jimp.read("img/brain.jpg").then(function(image) {
    Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_32_BLACK).then(function(font) {
      image.resize(542, 767);
      image.print(font, 16, 22, args[0]);
      image.write('brain.jpg');
    });
  });
  // brain.jpg doesn't exist until the second callback from above is run.
  await msg.channel.send({
    files: [
      "brain.jpg"
    ]
  });
  fs.unlinkSync('brain.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give where the image should be saved in which folder. You have to use the public folder inside which you should have the image folder where the image should be saved

So the code will be

```js
image.write("public/image/brain.png");
```

and before it, if you are using express you should write

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

so here we are telling our server that we are using public folder